# Whats the meaning of `@ ./src/views/main_components/cascade_selector.vue 9:2-211`?

Tags: vue.js

In my WebStorm, the compiled error log:

```
 @ ./src/views/main_components/cascade_selector.vue 9:2-211
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main
```

I don't understand the `9:2-211` in the error log.

does this means the cause error line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that on `line 9` and starting from the 2nd character to the 211st character, your code is having a problem.